# Menu Center Align Wordpress

Tags: alignment

This is regarding the website mothdesign.dk

As you can see the menu is aligned to the right for some reason. I have looked everywhere and I can’t see why.
I then tried to “force” it to be center-aligned with different CSS, but nothing works for me.

Anyone of you that might be able to help me with the correct CSS I need or tell me what I have done wrong?

Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this:

```
.onepress-menu {
    //your code
    float: right; 
    //mine code
    float: none !important;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Mine code sets the float to none(notice the !important keyword), width to "fit-content" so it fits its width to content's width, "margin: 0 auto" sets top and bottom margins to 0 and sets left and right margins to equal values.

Here is this code implemented:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyqNa.png)

Comment: Damn, that was fast. Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted answer if it helped you. You can do that by clicking the check button.

Comment: It's done now. I had to wait 5 minutes for some reason ;-)